# How to get actual photo from instagram real-time post data?

Tags: json, api, real-time, response, instagram

I subscribed to the `#tattoo` tag with instagram's real-time api and it's working fine, the problem is that I have no idea how to get the actual uploaded image when the post data looks like this:

```
[{"changed_aspect": "media", "subscription_id": XXXXXX, "object": "tag", "object_i
d": "tattoo", "time": 1334521880}]
```

It doesn't give me any info about the `media_id` or something like that, am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As noted in [their realtime API docs](http://instagr.am/developer/realtime/):

> The changed data is not included in the payload, so it is up to you how you'd like to fetch the new data. For example, you may decide only to fetch new data for specific users, or after a certain number of photos have been posted.

So it sounds like you just have to get the actual data via [their regular tag API](http://instagr.am/developer/endpoints/tags/), apparently using `GET /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`.  For you:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tattoo/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

This does certainly seem inelegant, since you'll have to sort out which of the recent updates you've already seen, but I don't see anything suggesting a better method.

Comment: That really sucks it's not efficient at all, I did read that part but I was hoping I was missing something oh wel..

Comment: You might want to hold off on accepting this answer, as someone else might have a brilliant idea or know some super-sekrit API to get the good info.  If they see an already accepted answer, they might not share their wisdom.  You've still got 6 days before the bounty expires, might as well get as much exposure as possible.

Comment: How would you even know if the media you're getting is the one that's changed??

Comment: I wish i would've read this before i spend time trying to work with this real time thingy. What a waste of time -_-

Comment: The alternative it to skip RealTime completely and just poll their system. Since you are going to have to do that anyways.

Comment: And worst still, you can't filter the regular API based on the time value from the poll data